# Why does the Rubocop default guidelines recommend parentheses in method definitions?

Tags: ruby, rubocop, ruby-style-guide

Why does Rubocop / the [community-driven Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) recommend parentheses in method definitions?

```
def my_method(param1, param2)
end
# instead of
def my_method param1, param2
end
```

Method calls are allowed with or without parentheses depending on the situation. However, my first impression is that lack of parentheses in method calls are much more potentially **ambiguous** than lack of parentheses in method definitions. Was there a reason behind it, e.g. to make code more fool-proof, or did it happen because of "historical reasons" or "because it was the most widespread style"?

**Clarification:**

*I am not asking for opinions about which style is easier to read.*

The lint `Lint/AmbiguousOperator` is based on the idea that `do_something *some_array` is ambiguous and a source for bugs ([Link](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_lint/#lintambiguousoperator)). I wondered if this is the same case for `Style/MethodDefParentheses` ([Link](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_style/#stylemethoddefparentheses)).

After going back to find the actual names of those Cops, my best guess right now is that there is no "technical" reason, but rather one is a proper "lint" and the other a "style" matter.

Comment: Doesn't it simply _read_ better?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That can be argued to be a matter of taste / tradition. That's why I ask if there are further reasons e.g. syntactical ambiguity. Ambiguity happens e.g. with the splat operator and multiplication e.g. `a *b` looks like both `a(*b)` and `a() * b()`; we would avoid `a *b` because it is more objectively a potential source for bugs. I don't see (yet) that being the case for methods in method declarations.

Comment: I'd estimate 90+% of ruby style guide to be based on nothing else than taste. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Hence the name, "style guide". Its purpose is to encourage community to write code in the similar style. You can join a project and start reading the code, without getting used to this project's idiosynratic coding conventions.

Comment: And no, off the top of my head, I too can't name a technical reason to prefer parenthesized method definitions.

Comment: There are two votes to close the question. It's not because it's a bad question, just that it calls for an opinion, which is verboden for SO questions.

Comment: There's really no way of knowing that I know of. That particular guideline appears to have been included with the initial commit of the README in the style guide repository: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/commit/dc31232fe357d08039fb59a66199b189cd7aa605#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R73 which actually seems to be based off of this other style guide: https://github.com/chneukirchen/styleguide/commit/9057d68f2234f164342b4fc23a48f5b3a31c8ffe#diff-70fa10fe169bac53cdb85e5c7723433bR37

Comment: @CarySwoveland I would contest that. I'm not asking for opinions on what's nicer, but rather, I'm asking _whether or not_ there are technical reasons to prefer one style. If not, then the answer would be "no, it was a matter of style". Changed to question for clarification.

Comment: I just wanted you to know that the two  members who voted to close may believe that the use of parentheses is only a stylistic issue, in which case an opinion is called for. I'm not saying that's my view. I am interested in the question, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rationale is omitted in the [initial commit](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/commit/dc31232fe357d08039fb59a66199b189cd7aa605), of which this rule was part, indicating that there was no particular technical reason for it.

The fact that the corresponding cop is placed in the `Style` department, rather than `Lint`, serves as further proof that this is a matter of just that, style.

Method definitions have a very simple syntax. The `def` keyword is (optionally) followed by arguments, which must be followed by a terminator (newline or `;`).

The possible variations are:

- single line method definitions,
- inline modifiers, e.g. `private`,
- default- and keyword arguments,
- splat- and block arguments.

All of these work fine both with and without parentheses. Furthermore, running a file with an unparenthesized method definition using the `-w` flag raises no warnings.

These factors together rule out the possibility that the parentheses are recommended to avoid ambiguity.